# Disjoint union measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am stuck in the following problem:

**Problem** Let $\Omega$ be an indexing set (possibly uncountable). Let $X_w$ be disjoint subsets of $Y$ and let $(X_w, \mathcal{X}_w, \mu_w)$ be measurable spaces for each $w\in \Omega$. Consider

$X:=\bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega} X_w$, $\mathcal{X}:=\left\{\bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega} U_w:~U_w\in \mathcal{X}_w\right\}$ and $\mu\left(\bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega} U_w\right):=\underset{\Gamma\subseteq \Omega}{\sup}\left\{\sum\limits_{w\in \Gamma}\mu_w(U_w): \Gamma~\mathrm{is~countable}\right\}.$

Prove that $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ is a measurable space.

I have shown that $\mathcal{X}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of sets. However, I am finiding it very difficult to prove the additivity of $\mu$.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** Following the ideas of drhab, I am trying to write a proof of the above problem.

Consider a family $\{A_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of pairwise disjoint sets.
Obviously for each $k$
$$A_k:=\bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega} U_w^{(k)}.$$
Let $A:=\bigsqcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k$. Now,

$$\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \mu (A_k):=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \underset{\Gamma\subseteq \Omega}{\sup}\left\{\sum\limits_{w\in \Gamma}\mu_w(U_w^{(k)}):~\Gamma \mathrm{~is~countable}\right\}.$$

Note that $$\mu(A):= \mu(\bigsqcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega} U_w^{(k)})$$

$$=\mu\left( \bigsqcup\limits_{w\in \Omega}\bigsqcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}}  U_w^{(k)}\right)$$

$$=\underset{\Gamma\subseteq \Omega}{\sup}\left\{ \sum\limits_{w\in \Gamma}\mu_w\left(\bigsqcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}}  U_w^{(k)}\right):~\Gamma \mathrm{~is~countable}\right\}$$
$$=\underset{\Gamma\subseteq \Omega}{\sup}\left\{ \sum\limits_{w\in \Gamma} \sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \mu_w\left( U_w^{(k)}\right):~\Gamma \mathrm{~is~countable}\right\}.$$
Since supremum is independent of $k$, we have

$$\mu (A):=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \underset{\Gamma\subseteq \Omega}{\sup}\left\{\sum\limits_{w\in \Gamma}\mu_w(U_w^{(k)}):~\Gamma \mathrm{~is~countable}\right\}.$$

Therefore,
$$\mu\left(\bigsqcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k\right)=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \mu (A_k).$$

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $A_{n}\in\mathcal{X}$ be disjoint with $A_{n}=\bigsqcup_{w\in\Omega}U_{w}^{n}$
and let $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$.

Observe that we can write $A=\bigsqcup_{w\in\Omega}V_{w}$ where $V_{w}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{w}^{n}$.

For every countable $\Gamma\subseteq\Omega$ we find that: $$\sum_{w\in\Gamma}\mu_{w}\left(V_{w}\right)=\sum_{w\in\Gamma}\mu_{w}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{w}^{n}\right)=\sum_{w\in\Gamma}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_{w}\left(U_{w}^{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{w\in\Gamma}\mu_{w}\left(U_{w}^{n}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$$

allowing us to conclude that: $$\sup_{\Gamma\subseteq\Omega}\left\{ \sum_{w\in\Gamma}\mu_{w}\left(V_{w}\right)\mid\Gamma\text{ countable}\right\} \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$$
or shorter: $$\mu\left(A\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$$

I leave the converse to you.

Comment: Thankyou@drhab, for your Answer,  I will try to prove the converse after understanding your proof.

Comment: Can we change the order of the sum@drhab?

Comment: Yes, because all terms are in $[0,\infty]$. In that case the order of counting has no impact.

Comment: I have tried to come up with a solution. I would request you to check (and edit!) as further@drhab._/\_